# Problem when retrieving elements from ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm having some problems when trying to retrieve elements from a ResultSet of type [ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY). The actual error message says

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
```

I think that changing the statement preparation method would solve the issue (something like

```
Statement sta = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE)
```

instead of just

```
Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
```

which uses TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY as default method)

...but I can't modify the code
I've read somewhere that MySQL v7.6 changed the default result type to TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY to improve performance, so is there a way to change it again? or, at least, to fix this issue?
I'm currently using the latest MySQL 8 release on a Debian 10 system.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to be a little bit more precise. MySQL has nothing like TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. This is a feature of the JDBC driver. This flag allows you to iterate through the Resultate only in one direction, what in 99.9% of the cases is what you Need. Please tell us what you like to do with the resultset so we can understand what you need

Comment: You need to show us the code in your application that is triggering that error, and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: (For what it is worth, there is no MySQL 7.6.  So perhaps you need to recheck the source of that supposed information.)